# Is there a way to create a build definition in TFS without a .sln or .proj file?

Tags: version-control, tfs, tfsbuild

So we're implementing automated CI into our build process. But we have quite a few old web site applications that do not have a solution or project file. Is there a way to create a build definition for these applications in TFS?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?

Comment: We're implementing TFS 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website projects must be upgraded to a Web Application in order for them to be built. Unless you write a `.proj` that handles the building process through the UpgradeTemplate.

In case of TFS 2015 and the new build engine, you're not required to have an MsBuild step in your build. If you want to run a powershell script, just use the Tools\Powershell option.

Just don't rely on the XAML builds, use the new VSO-Agent builds.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'll try the new VSO-Agent build to see if I can get that working. Adding a solution to the application ended up working for me on the xaml build.